# react-native-ble-manager returns nothing or event 'handleDiscoverPeripheral' is never triggered

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to get a list of available Bluetooth devices using this example.

(I don't use emulators, I've connected the phone via USB.)

This is an official example of the code.
[Code is here](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/master/example/App.js)

However, I can't see any devices. The event 'handleDiscoverPeripheral' is never triggered.

I should be able to see at least 2 devices.

This is my react native log

```
info Reloading app...
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1/1), done.

 LOG  Running "ArduinoBluetooth" with {"rootTag":1}
 WARN  VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.
 LOG  Permission is OK
 LOG  Scanning...
 LOG  Scan is stopped
 LOG  No connected peripherals
 LOG  []
 LOG  Scanning...
```

P.S
I've increased seconds of scanning to 30

```
BleManager.scan([], 30, true)
```

Also, all permssions are set.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
> ```

Comment: When you check your Android Settings -> Apps -> ArduinoBluetooth -> Permissions (or similar path depending on your OS), are location permissions enabled? Are you asked for location permission when you run the app?

Comment: yes, I have permissions, but it looks like a bug in the Bluetooth library :(

Comment: I notices that using gradle 6+ and newer SDK versions (29+) is messing with BLE, so I use gradle 5 for all BLE projects and sdk version 28
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip

Comment: Facing the same issue did you find any solutuion?

Comment: In order to make bluetooth work, you have to enable 'Location' on your phone as well, which is weird.